# Assign value of Optional to a variable if present

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

Hi I am using Java Optional. I saw that the Optional has a method ifPresent.

Instead of doing something like:

```
Optional<MyObject> object = someMethod();
if(object.isPresent()) {
    String myObjectValue = object.get().getValue();
}
```

I wanted to know how I can use the Optional.ifPresent() to assign the value to a variable.

I was trying something like:

```
String myValue = object.ifPresent(getValue());
```

What do I need the lambda function to be to get the value assigned to that variable?

Comment: What if your `myValue` line trying to say? "If object has a value, then myValue is the result of some unrelated function getValue()"? If so, then what happens if object doesn't have a value -- what do you want `myValue` to be then?

Comment: The MyObject class in my Optional has a getter which will return the myValue, so I definitely know that there's a value present if the Optional isn't empty. The value from the getValue() can never be null/not defined

Comment: But if the Optional *is* empty, what should be assigned to myValue?

Comment: You can shorthand the if-statement with a ternary like `String myValue = object.isPresent() ? object.get().getValue() : "some default string";`, but you still have to provide for the case where `object.isPresent()` comes back false.

Comment: If the Optional is null, I'd assign it to null

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of the `Optional`.

Comment: @azurefrog: That would be the second choice if there's no option for the usage of a lambda function to do that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I am assigning a different value to null, I am not throwing a null pointer exception. But anyway, wouldn't the assignment be possible?

Comment: It kinda looks like you're looking for [`Optional.orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-), unless I'm missing something? `String myValue = object.orElse(null)`

Comment: @yshavit Won't that return an `MyObject`, not a `String`?

Comment: Well, I need to call a specific method from the object I am returning. It needs to be like String myValue = object.get().getValue(); 

Could you explain a bit more as to how I can use the orElse method?

Comment: @azurefrog: You're exactly correct

Comment: @azurefrog Yes, good catch. So you would just chain it with a call to `map`: `String myValue = object.map(val -> val.convertSomehowToString()).orElse(null)` The `map` call turns the `Optional<MyValue>` into an `Optional<String>`, and the `orElse` call gets that string, or returns null if the original Optional was empty (thus meaning that the mapped Optional is also empty)

Comment: @yshavit: That perfectly worked! Woohoo! Thanks :) , could you post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: you can follow below url to see the examples : https://onlyfullstack.blogspot.com/2018/12/optional-in-java-8.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [#orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) or [orElseThrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) to improve the readbility of your code.

```java
Optional<MyObject> object = someMethod();
String myValue = object.orElse(new MyObject()).getValue();
```

---

```java
Optional<MyObject> object = someMethod();
String myValue = object.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new).getValue();
```

Comment: In the first case, you return an object of type MyObject when I am expecting a string. The second one works fine.

Comment: `object.orElse(new MyObject()).getValue()` will *always* create the new instance of `MyObject`. Instead it's much better to use `object.orElseGet(..)` which accepts a *function* which will be evaluated lazily.

Comment: @Asa is it **always** a good case to use `orElseGet`? I mean, for simple objects (mainly for objects that are already instantiated and constants) wouldn't the instance of the Function (represented here by the lambda expression) be more expensive?

Answer (score 20):

Quite late but I did following:

```
String myValue = object.map(x->x.getValue()).orElse("");
                           //or null. Whatever you want to return.
```

Comment: This works nice for cases when it is too complicated to create a new `MyObject` to return from `orElse`

Answer (score 11):

You need to do two things:

1. Turn your `Optional<MyObject>` into an `Optional<String>`, which has a value iff the original Optional had a value. You can do this using [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-): `object.map(MyObject::toString)` (or whatever other method/function you want to use).
2. Get the String value of of your `Optional<String>`, or else return a default if the Optional doesn't have a value. For that, you can use [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-)

Combining these:

```
String myValue = object.map(MyObject::toString).orElse(null);
```

Comment: Good explanation of `map()` and `orElse()`. +1. In comments the OP said to use `null` as the default value, but I'd strongly recommend using a non-null value. If `null` is used as the default value, then downstream users of `myValue` will have write extra code to guard against it.

Answer (score 2):

`.findFirst()` returns a `Optional<MyType>`, but if we add `.orElse(null)` it returns the get of the optional if `isPresent()`, that is (`MyType`), or otherwise a `NULL`

```
MyType s = newList.stream().filter(d -> d.num == 0).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Optional l = stream.filter..... // java 8 stream condition

```
        if(l!=null) {
            ObjectType loc = l.get();
            Map.put(loc, null);
        }
```

Comment: wrong, condition should be `l.isPresent()`