# Can this usage of Optional be made more functional

Tags: java, option-type

Is it possible to make this usage of `Optional` more function, i.e. replace the call to `isEmpty()` with one of the optional's methods that handles the null case?

```
public Iterable<User> getOrganisationUsers(final String organisationId) {

  Optional<Organisation> org = organisationRepository.findById(organisationId);

  if (org.isEmpty()) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
  return org.get().getUsers();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return org.map(Organisation::getUsers).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Answer (score 6):

More functional version of your code:

```
return organisationRepository.findById(organisationId)
        .map(Organisation::getUsers)
        .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
```

Comment: `Optional.isEmpty` exists in Java 11 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isEmpty()

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713235/10871900).

You can use the `Optional#orElse` method.

In your case, it would be:

```
return organisationRepository.findById(organisationId).map(org->org.getUsers()).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Comment: Ah, beat me by 4 secs

Comment: @AbishekAditya seems like I was lucky :)

Comment: Compile error because `Collections.emptyList()` doesn't return an `Organisation` object.

Comment: This won't compile. `orElse` require `Organisation` as parameter and you pass collection.

Comment: What is `getValue()`?

Comment: @Andreas The result of writing code on a mobile phone.